# Do plecos eat fish poop?

Tags: aquarium, community-aquarium, defecation, pleco

I'm wondering if plecos will eat the poop of other fish, specifically Molly fish. I've heard they eat algae growing on the aquarium walls but I don't know about what else their diet may include.

I'm very new with aquariums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think they will try to eat fish poop unless they're starving. They are great at eating algae off glass and (smooth) rocks and wood though. I would definitely get some sinking tablet or pellet type food for them just to make sure something gets to the bottom, past the mollies.

A pleco would also probably love you for throwing in some frozen bloodworms.